# How to unjoin the computer from domain in XP

Tags: windows-xp, domain-controller

Initially i had joined my XP to domain.
Now i have removed the OS with Domain COntroller.

Now  i want to join my xp to workgroup and when i do that it ask me for username and passowrd and then it says specified module does not exist

Now how can i manually unjoin

Answer (score 4):

Usually you can just click OK on that dialog without specifying credentials.

You need credentials to remove the computer account from the domain.  But you don't need domain credentials to switch the computer from domain to workgroup.  Removing the computer account from the domain is optional.

Comment: i tried that but it again says specified module can not be found

Comment: Try it when you are disconnected from the network.  I just verified that this does work by switching a Windows XP Pro computer from domain to workgroup, and I clicked OK without specifying credentials.

Comment: i tried same and it gives me error , any other way out

Comment: Doesn't sound familiar.  It may be another issue, like some kind of system or network component that is not installed or registered correctly.

Comment: The window says "There are was error connecting to "domain.com" . the specified module can not be found". The system is running ok without it but i am not able to unjoin it

Answer (score 3):

In my experience you have to enter the credentials of the Domain you are leaving.

Comment: You don't have to enter credentials. It will work without it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. If your not using it, switch to the "classic" style login screen by doing ctrl+alt+del+del  (yes, hit the del key twice).
2. There should be a drop down on the login dialog box that allows you to choose between logging in to the domain or the computer itself (called "this computer" I think).  Choose "this computer".
3. Login using the computers administrator account and password.
4. Right click on My Computer, choose Properties.
5. Choose the Computer Name tab.
6. Click the "Change..." button
7. In the Member of section, choose Workgroup and enter the workgroup name.

I've never tried this with the domain controller offline, so I can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: Actually i am trying that because as DC is offline  so i have to log  in via local admin account but it ask for ceredentials

Answer (score 1):

If the DC is offline how and which domain are you trying to Join???
If you want to unjoin, you could use David's technique. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL twice at login screen and login to the workstation locally with an administrator account, dont login to domain. Then you take properties of My Computer, go to Network tab and make your workstation member of a workgroup.

Let me know how it works for you...
Another way is, issue this command

C:>netsh interface ip reset reset.log
Your TCP/IP stack will be reset, all errors gone all memberships gone.

Comment: i want to unjoin not join

Answer (score 1):

From the command prompt:

```
wmic computersystem where name!=null call unjoindomainorworkgroup
```

You might or might not need credentials, per the conversation above.  WMIC is one hell of a tool, use it.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you might try using sysprep.  You'll need your Windows license key.

I've not done a machine with populated local accounts and I don't know what will happen to those local profiles.